# How to replace the group match, keeping everything else intact?

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

Regex isn't my strong point and I may be overcomplicating this but I've managed to come up with a pattern that appears to meets my needs.

```
\[img.*\].*photobucket.*(&#46;jpg)\[\/img.*\]
```

Here's a demo:

https://regex101.com/r/fo98tP/6

I am wanting to replace the group match (i.e. ".jpg") with ".jpg~original".

I've figured out how to get the matches with preg_match_all but I haven't a clue how to make the substitution and inject it back into the original block of text.

To give some background, this is to try and workaround the new hotlinking policy and the intention is for my PHP script to go through all messages on my phpBB forum and do the search and replace above and then update the post if there's been a match/replacement. If it could be done directly in MySQL even better but I'm trying to walk before I can run!

Very much appreciate any help; my head hurts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text)`.

So assuming your regex is correct, which it seems to be working. (Personally i would make some minor modifications like changing `\[img.*\]` to `\[img[^]]*\]`, but that might just be a style thing). All you need to do is add two more capture groups.

```
(\[img.*\].*photobucket.*)(&#46;jpg)(\[\/img.*\])
```

This allows you to use reference these capture group in your replacement.

```
 $replace = "$1$2~original$3";
```

Very simply - you are just rewriting the matched part of the original text to include the "~original" that you want.

The entire code block might look like this:

```
$text = "Steering damper mounts finished - without the connecting rod the damper would get bent:
[url=http&#58;//s557&#46;photobucket&#46;com/user/realboss7669/media
/C85A0F5D-413D-4779-9F09-
BD43BB798238_zpse8s6dxyu&#46;jpg&#46;html:jaeyh8wg]
[img:jaeyh8wg]http&#58;//i557&#46;photobucket&#46;com/albums
/ss16/realboss7669/C85A0F5D-413D-4779-9F09
BD43BB798238_zpse8s6dxyu&#46;jpg[/img:jaeyh8wg][/url:jaeyh8wg]";

$pattern  = "/(\[img.*\].*photobucket.*)(&#46;jpg)(\[\/img.*\])/i";

$replace = "$1$2~original$3";

 $text = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);
```

Comment: Thanks, I just never thought to define more groups! Thank you for the walk through and the actual PHP code. I did actually use sln's regex below though as does seem to me only 2 groups rather than 3 are required. Many thanks you you both! Saved me a lot of hair pulling.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can do a global replace, just use proper capture groups.

`&#46;jpg[/img:jaeyh8wg]`
`\       ^`
Since you want to insert here, you only need two groups to split it up.

Also, since you are looking for the closest closure's, better to use
non-greedy quantifiers `.*?`.

https://regex101.com/r/fo98tP/10

So it's a
Find `(\[img.*?\].*?photobucket.*?&#46;jpg)(\[\/img.*?\])`
Replace `$1~original$2`

Comment: Thanks for your input. This regex works perfectly. I just accepted Scott's answer as the PHP code made for an absolutely idiot proof answer. Many thanks!